# Google Maps Autocompletion API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm trying to embed the google maps autocompletion API into my project.
I did everything like it was written in the documentation, but it returns me this error : Uncaught InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function. Sometimes, when I reload 3 times the page, it finally works, which is quite strange...
Does somebody know where the problem could come from ? 
Here is the link where is the test that I did : http://www.dubair.ie/en/maps

Here is the code of the page (the link to the key script is in the head which is in an other file) :

```
{% extends "PlatformBundle::body.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="locationField" class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <textarea id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" autofocus class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="details" class="hidden">
        <input disabled id="street_number"/>
        <input disabled id="route"/>
        <input disabled id="locality"/>
        <input disabled id="postal_code"/>
        <input disabled id="country"/>
    </div>

    <script>
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

        // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
        // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
        // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
//            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initAutocomplete() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
            // location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {country: 'ie'}});

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            $('#details').removeClass('hidden').hide().slideDown('slow');

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
//                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you call API in the header, but you have the `initAutocomplete` function in the body of the HTML document. Sometimes the body is not yet loaded, sometimes it is.

Just put this code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=....&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

right BEFORE `</body>` tag (and remove it from header). So it would be the last element in the body of the HTML document. This way `initAutocomplete` should always be available when the API is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how you get this error, I also wonder how it may work sometimes.

I get this error: **InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement**

The error should be clear: You use a `<textarea>` ,  but the API requires an `<input>`

Replace:

```
<textarea id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" autofocus class="form-control"></textarea>
```

with

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" autofocus class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: I already tryied to put an input instead but it didn't change anything to the error...